# F# interactive notebook not showing Plotly chart

Tags: plotly, f#-interactive

I'm new to F# interactive notebook and XPlot.Plotly.

I tried the following code in the hopes to get a nice sine wave shown

```
#r "nuget: XPlot.Plotly"
open XPlot.Plotly

let series = [for x in -5.0 .. 0.1 .. 5.0 -> sin x]

Chart.Line(series)
```

Instead of the chart I get this [Table showing Height, Id and Width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV9Wn.png)

- I have tried VS Code 1.54.0-insider as well as 1.53.2 with same
  result
- I have tried several different versions of .NET Interactive
  Notebooks with same result
- I have tried several versions of .Net 5
  Sdk
- I have tried several versions of XPlot.Plotly

Please point out what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the interactive nuget package

```
#r "nuget: XPlot.Plotly"
#r "nuget: XPlot.Plotly.Interactive"
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks for your answer